# Is it possible to add an atlas variable to the SQL query when creating a virtual layer?

Tags: qgis, atlas, virtual-layer

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
select *
from table_a
inner join table_b
  on table_b.fid = table_a.id
  and table_b.code =  @atlas_featureid
```

I have tried this using QGIS 2.18.16 and QGIS 3.0 but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? Is there another approach to achieve this?

The alternative I could figure is to add a virtual layer without the last condition and symbolize just the ones that match the @atlas_featureid but this layer has about 100 times more features (≈ 300k) and it takes ages to work with it, it's not a viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Expression variables in your virtual Layers directly. Use the Expression function **var()** instead (i.e. `SELECT var('project_crs')`).

Unfortunately this won't help in your case, because virtual Layers only allow *global* and *Project* scoped Expression variables by now (I hope **Hugo Mercier** will catch up my feature request https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35867 to allow more Expression functions in future).

But to solve your problem at the moment, there is a possible workaround using a custom Python Expression function:

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def getAtlasFeatureId(layout,atlasLayerName,feature,parent):
    features = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(atlasLayerName)[0].getFeatures()
    id = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layout).atlas().currentFeatureNumber()
    idx = 0
    for feat in features:
        if idx==id:
            return(feat["id"])
        idx+=1
```

```
select *
from table_a
inner join table_b
  on table_b.fid = table_a.id
  and table_b.code =  getAtlasFeatureId('MyLayout','table_b')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, a little bit shorter:

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def getAtlasFeatureId(layout,feature,parent): 
    return QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layout).referenceMap().createExpressionContext().variable('atlas_featureid')
```

```
select *
from table_a
inner join table_b
  on table_b.fid = table_a.id
  and table_b.code =  getAtlasFeatureId('MyLayout')
```